# Make a New Variable From String In PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, variables

I have this script in PHP like this:

`echo "The results is $res";`

And now, I want make a new variable to save that script. What can I do?
I do this because the value of `$res` is always changing depending on the input entered from user.

Comment: What do you want to be saved in this "new variable"?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: your question is totally ambiguous... Can you explain it ?

Comment: Make a new variable for string code.. so, the result from `echo` saved into a new variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to save the script into a variable (let's call it `$script`), so that when `$res="foo"`, the result of `echo $script;` is "The result is foo" and when `$res="bar"`, `echo $script;` returns "The result is bar".

I don't think you can do this using a normal variable, but you certainly could do it as a function:

```
//The function
function get_res($res){
    return "The result is $res";
}

//The function call
$res = "foo";
print get_res($res);
$res = "bar";
print get_res($res);
```

This would output "The result is foo" the first time the function is called, and "The result is bar" the second time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = 'some resource';
$echo = 'The result is ' . $res;
echo $echo;
```

Is that what you want? If not, please clarify / simplify your question.